# Need tourist visa for Albania?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, albania

I have difficulty figuring out whether or not I need a visa to Albania. I do not have a passport from a visa exempt country, but I have a student visa to the UK and I study there currently. Now initially I thought I might have to apply for a visa, but after reading this, I am not so sure if it is necessary.

http://www.punetejashtme.gov.al/en/services/consular-services-online/visa-application

> b) Foreign nationals that have a valid multiple entry visa or a valid residence permit issued by the United States of America, Great Britain and Northern Ireland, with the condition that visa issued must have been used previously in the country issued

But then, I don't want to arrive there and be turned away, so could someone familiar with the situation clarify?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Not important, we have the info we need

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=AL&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=VS&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a valid multiple entry visa issued by the United Kingdom, if having used the visa to enter the United Kingdom at least once, for a maximum stay of 90 days.

According to this source, if your student visa (the sticker in the passport) is valid and allows for multiple entries, you're good.

Even if it's expired or only single-entry, however, your quoted link states that the UK residence permit (the card) can also be used if valid. However, Timatic does not state this, which is why you'd be denied boarding on a plane to Albania unless the visa if multiple entry and still valid.

This seems to be an error in Timatic, so I'll write to the team and ask them to look into and correct it.